# HTML dropdown select for generated list of users only passes value of first user

Tags: javascript, html, express, dom, ejs

I am creating a template that pulls in a list of users from the db, and each user row has a dropdown select to change their user type (this is an admin page). I'm trying to get the dropdowns to submit the change asynchronously. Right now, I'm only able to get dropdown select values from the first user. I'm trying to get the functionality to work for all the users listed on the page. Here's the (EJS and JS) code:

**users.ejs**

```
<table class="table">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                          ...
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="user-body">
                    <% for (let user of users) { %>
                        <tr class="user">
                            <th scope="row"><%= user.user_id %></th>
                            <td><%= user.username %></td>
                            <td><%= user.email %></td>
                            <td><%= user.user_type %></td>
                            <td>
                                <select name="user-types" id="user-type-select" class="form-select mb-3">
                                    <option value="admin" >Admin</option>
                                    <option value="dealer" >Dealer</option>
                                    <option value="user" >User</option>
                                </select>
                                <input type="hidden" value="<%= user.user_id %>" name="userId" id="userId">
                                <button id="update-user-type" class="button" type="button">Update User Type</button>
                            </td>
                            <td><%= user.is_active %></td>
                        </tr>
                    <% } %>

                </tbody>
            </table>
```

**adminUsersScript.js**

```
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains("button")) {
            const selectElement = document.getElementById("user-type-select")
            const selectElementValue = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].value;
            const text = selectElement.options[selectElement.selectedIndex].text;
            //const selectUserId = document.getElementById("userId")
            //const userIdValue = selectUserId.value
            //console.log(userIdValue)
            console.log(selectElementValue)
            console.log(text)
        }

    })
```

Comment: If you create multiple elements with the same id, in this case `user-type-select` in the `<select>` then that leads to problems, because ids are supposed to be unique.

Answer (score 2):

You need a unique `id` for your `<select>` elements:

```html
<select name="user-types" id="user-type-select-<%= user.user_id %>" class="form-select mb-3">
```

Also, assign a unique identifier to your buttons, so you can find out which one was clicked:

```html
<button id="update-user-type-<%= user.user_id %>" data-userid="<%= user.user_id %>" class="button" type="button">Update User Type</button>
```

And in JS, modify line 3 to select the `<select>` element which "belongs" to the clicked button:

```js
document.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
        if (e.target && e.target.classList.contains("button")) {
            const userId = e.target.getAttribute("data-userid");
            const selectElement = document.getElementById("user-type-select-" + userId);
            // ...
```

Comment: Wow, I've never thought of invoking the query method with a regex! It seems that the array index after the query selector call controls which line is being listened to statically (if I use 0, it only passes the first value regardless of the button clicked, if I use 2, it only passes the value change from the 3rd line regardless of which line's button I clicked). This has been a tremendous aid, but if I can ask, Is there a way to change that value dynamically?

Comment: @DeltaFlyer Sure thing, I have updated the answer for you